# Rails bootstrap flash not fading

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am making rails app using bootstrap. Unfortunately, I cannot add whole bootstrap.CSS file to my web app because CSS are overriding each other. As an alternative solution, I just take out certain CSS from bootstrap for few things. One of them is flash. I want to show flash successfully when I send the email. Now I have two problems.

1. Flash box shows above where nav bar is. It doesn't show up as a box on top of the screen. Look at the image below.
   [image]

What I want is below:
[image]

2. I put `fade in` CSS but it never gets triggered.

Below are my codes:

```
//in my MailerController.rb
flash[:success] = "Thank you for your message! We will get back to you shortly."

//application.html.erb

    <body>
        <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type} fade in") %>
        <% end %>
</body>
```

CSS I took out from Bootstrap:

```
.alert {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.alert h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit;
}
.alert .alert-link {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.alert > p,
.alert > ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.alert > p + p {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.alert-dismissable,
.alert-dismissible {
  padding-right: 35px;
}
.alert-dismissable .close,
.alert-dismissible .close {
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  right: -21px;
  color: inherit;
}
.alert-success {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
.alert-success hr {
  border-top-color: #c9e2b3;
}
.alert-success .alert-link {
  color: #2b542c;
}
.alert-info {
  color: #31708f;
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bce8f1;
}
.alert-info hr {
  border-top-color: #a6e1ec;
}
.alert-info .alert-link {
  color: #245269;
}
.alert-warning {
  color: #8a6d3b;
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border-color: #faebcc;
}
.alert-warning hr {
  border-top-color: #f7e1b5;
}
.alert-warning .alert-link {
  color: #66512c;
}
.alert-danger {
  color: #a94442;
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebccd1;
}
.alert-danger hr {
  border-top-color: #e4b9c0;
}
.alert-danger .alert-link {
  color: #843534;
}

.fade {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;
       -o-transition: opacity .15s linear;
          transition: opacity .15s linear;
}
.fade.in {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Can anyone let me know what problems I'm having?

Comment: It is stated here (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-dismissible) that you'd need the bootstrap JS for alerts - did you include it? Additionally this (https://gist.github.com/roberto/3344628#gistcomment-1291351) looks a bit different from your code. About positioning: You need to include your code at the place (e.g. wrapping div below your navigation) you want your flash-message/alert to appear, not at the top first in the body.

Comment: @Seika85, I am not using alert-dismissible but `fade in` CSS.

Comment: Did you include the bootstrap-JS? You're not using `.alert-dismissible`, but at your "what i want" screenshot it seems exactly like it. To keep your message box in boundaries you need a wrapping container having the position and width you want your message to have. And then you need more CSS from bootstrap styling this box (as you stated you only copied parts of it).

Comment: @Seika85, I added a JS file and it started working as I expected. Still not dismissing but user can at least click 'x' button to kill the flash. The problem now is that the flash doesn't hover but gets placed on top of nav. Do you know which bootstrap CSS triggers hover action?

Comment: It does not hover originally. As I said, you need a wrapper in which you put the messages. This wrapper you can position absolute (or fixed) so all messages appearing in it will visually hover your page. I'll write an answer for our conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the Bootstrap-JS for the functionality.

To position your messages like you want (e.g. out of the documents flow anywhere you want on the screen) with specific dimensions, you need a wrapper.
This Wrapper is a DIV having the dimensions you want (like width) and the `position` property set to *absolute* or *fixed*.

**some HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="flash-message-wrapper">
        <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
            <%= content_tag(:div, message, class: "alert alert-#{message_type} fade in") %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
    <!-- more content -->
</body>
```

**some CSS**

```
#flash-message-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px; right: 100px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c4q8nn6w/1/

Using `fade in` initial will not render a fade effect. Just use `fade` and add the `in` per JS (e.g. on load or callback). I used an timeout to show you the actual effect.

Comment: sweet! Thank you so much for the answer! Is there a way to fix the position of alert in the middle? is there any CSS for that? And it seems like fade in is not working even in your fiddle example.

Comment: You just have to position and style the `#flash-message-wrapper` as you like. See CSS here: https://jsfiddle.net/c4q8nn6w/2/. And the fade-in effect is working in my browsers.

Comment: must be my browser then. Fade in doesn't work for some reason haha. Do you use chrome?

Comment: Yes. I tested it successfully in Chrome 51, FF 47, IE 11, Opera 38 and even Safari 5.1 - all on Win7 Pro x64 (if that matters to you). All tested browsers had the flash-messages fade in.